# Is it possible to create a forced focus with a dual layer of images in order to Avoid eye strain with Virtual and Augmented Reality?

Tags: real-time, virtual-reality, perspective

Would eye tracking allow for the alignment of a dual layered image (a google glass like device and a screen or projection) to provide a way to force the focus of the eyes into to a real life equivalent of the perceived distance in a similar, but healthier, way in which Anaglyph 3D and other stereoscopic or perspective tricks on a single 2d image confuse the brain into thinking you are?

[Resolving the Vergence-Accommodation Conﬂict in Head Mounted Displays](https://www.cs.umd.edu/sites/default/files/scholarly_papers/Kramidarev.pdf) talks about using eye tracking for "Foveated rendering" and "gaze dependent rendered depth-of-ﬁeld". There are "Deformable Mirrors in Virtual Retinal Displays" and "Liquid and Electroactive Lens Displays"

"EVALUATION METHODS We establish four general evaluation strategies to evaluate VAC solutions: (1) subjective user studies, (2) direct measurement of occulomotor responses (3) measurements of physiological fatigue indicators and (4) assessment of brain activity via such tools as EEG or fMRI."

There are [software approaches](https://medium.com/vrinflux-dot-com/vergence-accommodation-conflict-is-a-bitch-here-s-how-to-design-around-it-87dab1a7d9ba#.n80klmszc) to minimise this effect;

"Use long viewing distances when possible — focus cues have less influence as the distance to the display increases. Beyond 1 meter should suffice.
Match the simulated distance in the display and focal distance as well as possible.
Move objects in and out of depth at a pace that gives the user’s eyes more time to adjust.
Maximize the reliability of other depth cues. Accurate perspective, shading realism, and other visual cues that convey realistic depth...
Minimize the consequences of VAC by making existing conflicts less salient."